# Excluir um registro em struct

Tags: c

Estou criando um cadastro usando `struct`, onde devo ter um menu para inserir,exibir,deletar e sair do programa.

Minha dificuldade é para criar a função deletar , eu coloco um valor nulo no ponteiro da posição que será deletada, recuo todos os registros uma posição, posteriormente usaria o `realloc` para diminuir uma posição do vetor. Mas aquele espaço alocado, que depois que eu deletei, ficará disponível para uso de outras variáveis?

O código está um pouco bagunçado, pois ainda estou aprendendo alocação dinâmica.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct cadastro{
    char nome[20];
    int idade;
};

cadastro *p;

int num, num_novo, num_old, realoca=0;
char opcao,op;
void cadastra();
void exibe();
void menu();

main()
{       
    do{
        menu();

        printf("\tOpcao: "); scanf("%d",&opcao); fflush(stdin);

            switch(opcao){
                case 0:
                    break;

                case 1:{
                    do{
                        cadastra();
                        printf("Deseja cadastrar mais (s/n): "); op=getchar(); fflush(stdin);

                    }while(toupper(op)!='N');
                    break;
                }

                case 2:
                    exibe();
                    break;

                default:
                    printf("Opcao invalida.\n\n");
            }   
    }while(opcao!=0);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    printf("\t[0] Sair\n\t[1] Cadastrar\n\t[2] Exibe\n\t[3] Excluir\n");

}

void cadastra()
{
    if(realoca==0){
        printf("Numero de cadastros: "); scanf("%d",&num); fflush(stdin);

        p = (cadastro *)calloc(num, sizeof(cadastro));

        int i;
        for(i=0; i<num; i++){
            printf("Cadastro %d\n",i+1);
            printf("Nome: "); gets(p[i].nome);
            printf("Idade: "); scanf("%d",&p[i].idade);fflush(stdin);
            printf("\n\n");

        }
        realoca = 1;
    }else{

        num_old=num;
        num=num+1;

        p = (cadastro*)realloc(p,num);

        int i;

        for(i=num_old; i<num; i++){
            printf("Cadastro %d\n",i+1);
            printf("Nome: "); gets(p[i].nome);
            printf("Idade: "); scanf("%d",&p[i].idade);fflush(stdin);
        }
    }
}

void exibe()
{
    int j;
    if(p==NULL)
        printf("\t -- Cadastro vazio. --\n\n");


    else{

        for(j=0; j<num;j++){

            printf("Pessoa %d\n\n");
            printf("Nome: %s\n",p[j].nome);
            printf("Idade: %d",p[j].idade);
            puts("\n\n");
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Correções**

O código apresenta de facto alguns avisos de erros de coisas que precisam de ser corrigidas.

Uma delas é o `typedef` que não tem o nome do tipo a que se esta a renomear:

```
typedef struct cadastro{
    char nome[20];
    int idade;
};
```

Que devia ser:

```
typedef struct cadastro{
    char nome[20];
    int idade;
} cadastro; //faltava nome de renomeação para completar o typedef
```

A `opcao` está a ser utilizada como um inteiro tanto na leitura `scanf("%d",&opcao);` como no `switch`, no entanto foi declarada como `char`:

```
char opcao,op;
```

Deve então ser alterada para `int` para ser consistente com a sua utilização:

```
int opcao;
char op;
```

No `exibe()` um dos `printf` tem um argumento em falta:

```
void exibe()
{
    ...
        for(j=0; j<num;j++){
            printf("Pessoa %d\n\n"); 
        ...
```

Devendo esse ficar:

```
printf("Pessoa %d\n\n", j); //agora com j para indicar o numero da pessoa
```

E a própria assinatura do main:

```
main()
{
```

Deve ser no minimo passar a ser `int main() {`, até para ser consistente com o `return 0` que está a ser feito dentro do mesmo.

**Função para remover**

Quando á função `deletar` que indica, pode ser feita exatamente com a lógica que indicou, andando todos os elementos para trás a partir da posição pretendida e chamando o `realloc` para reduzir o tamanho do array em 1 unidade, assim:

```
void deletar(){
    printf("Qual a posição a excluir?");
    int pos;
    scanf("%d", &pos);
    pos-- ; //para ajustar aos indices que começam em 0

    if (pos >= 0 && pos < num){ //se a posição é valida
        int i;

        //andar todos um para trás a partir da posição a remover
        for (i = pos;i < num - 1; ++i){ 
            p[i] = p[i + 1];
        }

        p = realloc(p, --num * sizeof(cadastro)); //reduzir o tamanho do array em 1 unidade
    }
}
```

Esta solução de remoção garante a ordem dos elementos que o array já tinha. Se a ordem dos elementos não for relevante pode pegar no ultimo elemento, substituir pela posição a ser removida e fazer diretamente o `realloc`, que é mais eficiente:

```
if (pos >= 0 && pos < num){ //se a posição é valida
    p[pos] = p[--num];
    p = realloc(p, num * sizeof(cadastro));
}
```

**Melhorias**

A função `cadastra()` podia ser simplificada, porque quando já fez uma realocação, no `else`:

```
else{
    num_old=num;
    num=num+1;

    p = (cadastro*)realloc(p,num);

    int i;

    for(i=num_old; i<num; i++){
        printf("Cadastro %d\n",i+1);
        printf("Nome: "); gets(p[i].nome);
        printf("Idade: "); scanf("%d",&p[i].idade);fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

Está a utilizar um ciclo para adicionar sempre apenas uma posição, uma vez `num_old=num; num=num+1;` vai fazer com que `num` seja sempre 1 a mais que `num_old`. Logo o ciclo não é necessário, podendo ficar o `else` simplesmente assim:

```
else{
    num_old = num++;
    p = realloc(p,num);
    printf("Cadastro %d\n",num_old);
    printf("Nome: "); gets(p[num_old].nome);
    printf("Idade: "); scanf("%d",&p[num_old].idade);fflush(stdin);
}
```

Nem a variável `realoca` seria necessária. Para não a utilizar podia-se iniciar o array `p` com o valor apropriado, `NULL`, e testar esse valor diretamente no `if`:

```
int num, num_novo, num_old /*, realoca=0*/;
cadastro *p = NULL;

...

void cadastra()
{
    if(p == NULL){ //calloc
        ...
        //realoca = 1; também deixa de ser necessária
    }else{ //realloc
        ...
    }
}
```

Podiam ser feitas outras melhorias, mas apenas indiquei as de cima para fazer com que o código fique similar ao que tinha.

[Código com todas as revisões que indiquei online para poder testar](https://onlinegdb.com/SyMNKnNwW)

Nota: Tive de fazer alguns ajustes nesta versão online para que a entrada de valores funcionasse corretamente, tais como substituir `getchar` e `gets` pelo `scanf` correspondente.

Answer (score 0):

Essa é a solução mais simples:

```
void remove(){
int n_remover;
exibe()
printf("Digite o numero de quem voce quer remover");
scanf("%d",&n_remover);
p[d] = p[num-1] //coloca o ultimo no lugar do q você quer remover
num--; //você diminui o tamanho do vetor
p = (cadastro*) realloc(p,num*sizeof(cadastro)); //desaloca o espaço que sobrou
}
```

Outra solução seria remover o elemento da posição e shiftar o vetor.